# Print hashmap contents in JSON

Tags: java

I have a hashmap, in which I am storing list of cars by their name a person owns.

```
Map<String,List<String>> personCarMap = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
```

The key is person id, and the value is the list of car names. In the value, I would also like to store the purchase date. All of this is being fetched from database. How do I have a key map to two different columns in the db?

This is the code I have so far.

```
public static JSONObject fetchPersonCarInfo(String person) throws SQLException
{
    Map<String,List<String>> personCarMap = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;        
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:myDriver:myDatabase",username,password);
        statement = connection.prepareStatement("select personId,car,purchase_date from carz where person = ?");
        rs = statement.executeQuery();          
        while(rs.next()) {  
            List<String> carIds;
            if(personCarMap.containsKey(rs.getString(carId))) {
                carIds = personCarMap.get(rs.getString(personId));
            } else {
                carIds = new ArrayList<String>();
            }               
            carIds.add(rs.getString(carId));
            carIds.add(rs.getTimestamp(purchase_date).toString()); //This is where I have a doubt.
            personCarMap.put(rs.getString(carId),carIds);           
        }
        for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> personCarMapEntry:personCarMap.entrySet())
        {
            jObj.put("personID", personCarMapEntry.getKey());
            jObj.put("carID", personCarMapEntry.getValue());                
        }
    } finally{
        DatabaseFunctions.closeDBResources(null, statement, rs);
    }       
    return jObj;
}   
}
```

I want my JSON object to show {personId, [carId,purchasedate]}. Please suggest how do I have the JSON array also print out purchase date? I see the output coming clearly for personId, and carId, but I am unable to figure out how to add purchase date, so need your expert advise.

Comment: You are asking for invalid JSON. Perhaps `{personId: [carId,purchasedate]}`?

Comment: Yes, Paul. I meant for what I have now, I got -  {personId:12345 carID:[34567,23456]}, but for what I want to have, I need - {personId: [carId,purchasedate]}

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a List of custom object with two properties carId and purchaseDate.

```
Map<String,List<ClassNameOfCustomObject>> personCarMap = new HashMap<String,List<ClassNameOfCustomObject>>();
```

This way you will able to store the purchaseDate alongwith the carId in personCarMap.

Comment: No, there is no option to create a custom object in my case.

Comment: Well, in that case, you should start building the JSONObject straight away and not build that intermediate Map.

Comment: Do you need something like {"personId": [{"carId": "", "purchaseDate": ""}]}? Also, I would recommend to first test whatever json structure you are trying to build at [link](http://jsonlint.com)

Comment: Yes, I need something like this. The idea is, I need both carId, and the purchaseDate of the car along with personId for a given person (method argument is person)

Comment: This answer is over complicated. @singh.jagmohan has it right in comment to use JSONObject instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the `JSONObject` directly. It has some convenient methods.

```
public static JSONObject fetchPersonCarInfo(String person) throws SQLException
{
    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;        
    try {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:myDriver:myDatabase",username,password);
        statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT personId, car, purchase_date FROM carz WHERE person = ?");
        statement.setString(1, person);
        rs = statement.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()) {
            jObject.put("personId", rs.getString("personId");

            JSONObject purchase = new JSONObject();
            // there is no column with name carId in above query.
            purchase.put("carId", rs.getString("car");
            purchase.put("purchasedate", rs.getTimestamp("purchase_date").toString());  
            jObject.append("purchases", purchase);
        }
    } finally{
        DatabaseFunctions.closeDBResources(null, statement, rs);
    }       
    return jObj;
}
```

This will produce JSON like this:

```
{
    "personId": "ABC123",
    "purchases": [
        {"carId": "abc123", "purchasedate": "2013-01-01 00:00:00"},
        {"carId": "def456", "purchasedate": "2013-01-02 00:00:00"}
    ]
}
```

It was a little hard understanding what you wanted your JSON to look like, but I think this is it. In any case, this JSON structure is a good one for your data.

Comment: Let me try and see if this will work. Thanks so much.

Comment: So you are not using a map here at all? I'll need to use a map. The reason being, I need to check if the map contains the key - if yes, fetch the value. If not, create a new arraylist, and add the values.

Comment: Can you please let me know?

Comment: @rickygrimes, there is no need to do that, but if you want to, look at the available methods on `JSONObject`, which is essentially a `Map`.

Comment: Okay. There is no append method btw.

Comment: @rickygrimes, http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#append(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)